# VB.NET | Cannot duplicate tabs properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a browser in VB.NET, but I'm having problems to create a button that can "duplicate tabs" in my tabcontrol (called Child_TabControl). Well, I have this code and it seems to works fine in the first tab, but when I try to click on the duplicate button in the generated tab, it duplicates again the URL in the first tab. Anyone can help me to solve this?

```
Private Async Sub Btn_Duplicate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Duplicate.Click
    Dim newTab As New TabPage
    Dim child_header As New Tabs_Child_Header
    Dim browser As New WebView2 


    'Events
    Await browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async
    AddHandler browser.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested, AddressOf Browser_NewWindowRequested

    AddHandler browser.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted, Sub()
                                                             child_header.Text_Url.Text = browser.Source.AbsoluteUri
                                                         End Sub

    AddHandler child_header.Btn_Back.Click, Sub()
                                                browser.GoBack()
                                            End Sub

    AddHandler child_header.Btn_Foward.Click, Sub()
                                                  browser.GoForward()
                                              End Sub

    AddHandler child_header.Btn_Update.Click, Sub()
                                                  browser.Reload()
                                              End Sub

    AddHandler child_header.Btn_Duplicate.Click, AddressOf Btn_Duplicate_Click

    'Load Child

    Child_TabControl.TabPages.Add(newTab)
    child_header.TopLevel = False
    child_header.Visible = True
    child_header.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    newTab.Controls.Add(child_header)
    'Child_TabControl.SelectTab(newTab)

    'Load Webview

    newTab.Text = Child_TabControl.SelectedTab.Text
    child_header.Panel_Navigate.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.Source = New Uri(Text_Url.Text)
End Sub
```

I don't know how to reference (as Me) to my control Tabs_Child_Header dinamically created previously.

Comment: Well the question would be, in your method to duplicate tabs, what exactly is the value of Text_Url.Text, are you 100% sure that is what you expect at the time you navigate to it?

Comment: The text in the Text_Url.Text is the current URL running at the page. I want to click in the duplicate button so my tab control creates a new tab and a new form (Tabs_Child_Header).In the first tab, it runs well, but when I am at the second tab or third tab, he keeps taking the TextURL.Text value from the first tab. Actually I dont know how to make a reference to my Tabs_Child_Header created dinamically. When I use "Me.TextURL.Text" the reference are made to the first tab (beucase the first tab is not created dinamically). Sorry I it is confusing, I'm quite new in Vb.Net

Comment: Just to complement: Tabs_Child_Header have a duplicate button as well, but I'm not getting how I reference to my textbox TextURL created in "Dim child_header As New Tabs_Child_Header" previously. :-(

Comment: I want to get the text inside the textbox (TextUrl) into the current dinamically created form, because the button to duplicate must duplicate the current URL always. (the textbox already have the code to update if the user change the page)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? That means all of the code and instruction for us to spin up Visual Studio and to replicate the issue you're seeing.